# videojs HLS decrypt key

Tags: encryption, http-live-streaming, video.js

I need to play encrypted files with videojs, backend developer changed the logic and sends decrypt key beside the file in api and that is not present in playlist, so I neeed to process this key and pass it to player to use this key instead of reading that from a URI, do you know how I can do this?

player automatically will perform a xhr request to this uri which is not ok and I need to override this part to read key from my custom function instad of performing this request.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the `URI` to your Restfull API, it responds to your key.

If you use S3 to host, you can change to S3 URL file key

for example:

```
#API
URI="https://dicom-interactive.com/fetch-video-key"

#S3
https://your-bucket.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/video/file.key
```

Comment: Could you please guild me to play this file after receiving the key?